# "not something is defined" vs "something is not defined"

Tags: twig

Is there a difference between the notation `not something is defined` vs `something is not defined`. To me it looks like the same behavior but maybe I miss something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the compiled result is the same. Guess it's just a preference

*Snippet*

```
{% if not something is defined %}

{% endif %}

-----------------------------------------

{% if something is not defined %}

{% endif %}
```

*Compiled result*

```
    protected function doDisplay(array $context, array $blocks = [])
    {
        $macros = $this->macros;
        // line 1
        if ( !array_key_exists("something", $context)) {
            // line 2
            echo "
";
        }
        // line 4
        echo "
-----------------------------------------

";
        // line 7
        if ( !array_key_exists("something", $context)) {
            // line 8
            echo "
";
        }
    }
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/khirdh)